# NW.JS - How to use chrome.desktopCapture to just save a PNG screenshot of user's desktop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, node-webkit, nw.js

I am using NW.JS with the latest Chrome Apps API capabilities.
In my app, **I need to take a screenshot the user's desktop to a PNG file** so I can sample color from that saved image.

I noticed a **chrome.desktopCapture** function in the Chrome API but all the samples I tried for that were to capture and stream one's desktop over the network and not merely saving an image of the desktop. Is there any way to do it with this API or any other function in the Chrome API?

Comment: There's no such API for [chrome **apps**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index). Why is the question tagged with `google-chrome-extension` tag?

Comment: Looks kinda silly that there isn't such function for a mere screenshot and there's one for broadcasting your screen's image. I suppose I am out of options there. Also it was tagged google-chrome-extension because NW.JS supports some of that API too (not sure if there was a function there instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var win = nw.Window.get();
var fs = require('fs');

win.capturePage(function(buffer) {
    fs.writeFile(process.cwd() + '/screenshot.png', buffer, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        console.log('Image is saved');
    });
}, { format : 'png', datatype : 'buffer'} );
```

Or better would be to use https://github.com/fweinb/node-webkit-screenshot module for this

Comment: This captures the window not the desktop. Also the node-webkit-screenshot module seems that it captures remote URLs only.